# Is there a way to open a file that is on a local network on a users computer from a link on a webpage?

Tags: php, html, file, networking, hyperlink

I am making a php page that will go on my companies corporate intranet, which will be hosted on a domain. We have files on a local network that are accessible through My Network Places. I would like to be able to make a link that acts as a shortcut to a file on the network, much like a shortcut you would have on your desktop, rather than have the link download it to the user's machine. The user would click the link and excel opens the document from its network location. Is this possible and if so how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Yeah, I think the <a> tag would do the job with the proper file:// value in the http attribute

Comment: Most browsers will refuse to follow links to local (`file://`) URLs from nonlocal documents. Some, like MSIE, will let you disable this by placing a site into a "low security" zone; others, like Chrome, will not.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you will need the full path ( unc path)

```
<a href="file:\\servername\path\file.doc">get file ( right click 'save target as')</a>
```

Comment: I do not want to download it/save it. I want to be able to one it.

Comment: i understand, but some client browsers will inhibit or prohibit the direct open ( try to open using the browser ) so adding the tip might aid the user .. is why I threw that in there )